# gmaps4Rails - json is being returned empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I installed gmaps4rails in my application.

The view related stuff seems to be working, since the an empty google maps shows up. So I am thinking that I installed it correctly.

I followed the quick start on the github page:

My controller:

```
def map
    @businesses = Business.all
    @json = @businesses.to_gmaps4rails

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json:@businesses}
    end
  end
```

My view:

```
=gmaps4rails(@json)
=@json
```

I print `@json` and realized that the value is empty i.e. `[]`

My business.rb model:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reviews

  attr_accessible :address, :description, :name, :phone, :urbanization, :url, :city_id

  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :slugged

  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
    # "#{self.address}, #{self.urbanization}, #{self.city.name}"
    "619 Johnson Street, Kingston, ON"
  end
end
```

I hard coded the address for testing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmaps4rails doesn't geocode on the fly for performance concerns.

`to_gmaps4rails` returns empty json if objects don't have lat or long.

You should preprocess your objects (simply save them).

Comment: I had the same issue. It did the trick the first time, but then now I want to update the lat lon again and it wouldn't do it after a simple save. Any ideas? Joel

Comment: @joelmaranhao read the doc: the gmaps boolean prevents geocoding to be triggered each time the object is saved. Set the boolean to false if you want to geocode

Comment: I just found out and didn't have the time to cancel my comment. But please don't throw a 'read the doc', I love gmaps4rails and I have read the doc many times. May be not corretly ... but don't make me feel like a teen that didn't do his homework. Please!

Comment: @joelmaranhao :) I guess I'm sometimes a bit harsh. Please share if doc is unclear or better, push modifications!

Comment: no the doc, the gem are great. only I am getting old and I have been working too many long hours. thx again

Comment: @joelmaranhao I know that feeling ;)

Comment: @apneadiving if there is anything in the docs about the gmaps boolean, I cannot find it either... unfortunately since it has the same name as your top-level method gmaps() it's not easy to google it either. I'll be happy to write up the gmaps field documentation, if you'll provide a link to some minimal documentation of how/when it's used. For example, it looks like it is reset automatically to true each time the geocode is done, I'm not sure?

Comment: @jpwynn description lives (here)[https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization] but basically it's exactly what you said: if geocoding is ok, the gmaps bool is set to true to prevent later queries. My advice: use the `process_geocoding` option and pass it a proc or a symbol

Comment: I added a little additional info to the page (which I had a hard time finding) it's this page: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add longitude and latitude to all your objects, you can run this in the rails console to get all coordinates.

```
Venue.all.each do |venue|
  geo_data = Gmaps4rails.geocode(venue.gmaps4rails_address)
  venue.update_attributes(latitude: geo_data[0][:lat], longitude: geo_data[0][:lng])
  sleep(1)
end
```